# Boostrap 3, icon on the same line of textbox, should I really use a table?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to put the `glyphicon-question-sign` on the same line of the textbox. The only working solution I found is using a table but it shrinks the textbox length. I could stretch it back with CSS but I'm concerned about page responsiveness. What I am after is to have all the textbox of the same width and for some of them a clarification icon on the right.

How would you solve this?

Thanks.

```
<div class="form-group" id="vatNumberDiv">
   @Html.LabelFor(m => m.vatNumber, new {@class = "col-md-2 control-label"})
   <div class="col-md-10">
      @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.vatNumber, new {@class = "form-control"})
      @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.vatNumber, "", new {@class = "text-danger"})
   </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group" id="destCodeDiv">
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.destCode, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        <table>
           <tr>
              <td>
                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.destCode, new { @class = "form-control" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.destCode, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
              </td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-question-sign" aria-hidden="true" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" title="Description text..." style="font-size: 1.2em"></span>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: You could use a input group... [see here](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/components/#input-groups)

Comment: It is not the same thing, sorry.

Comment: This can be done without a table but your code is too specific to test. Do you have the html output?

Comment: @abenci doesn't this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mfqr8dbp/2/) do what you want? it uses the input group

Comment: @zgood: Not bad but you need to satisfy `<div class="col-md-10">` as in previous rows.

Comment: @abenci ya just changed them to `col-sm-10` for the demo because of the small iframe window... you can easily replace it with `col-md-10`

Comment: @zgood: I've edited your script adding the `EU VAT number` row and the textbox length is not the same

Comment: ohh... you want the icon outside of the container? like hanging off at the end?

Comment: Yes, that's correct.

Comment: sorry for the mis-understanding. You can do something pretty easy with `position: absolute` then... like in this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mkfyL2p1/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are couple of methods.  Glyphicons are nothing but text/font and so you can make use of `form-control-static` using two methods.

In keeping with the grid layout you can shorten your fields by 1 and make room for a `col-**-1`

Or... There is also nothing preventing you from setting an overriding width of your inputs, it's just that a `form-control` defaults to 100% of the `col`.  You can override the `form-control` with some CSS and set both the `form-control` and `form-control-static` to `inline-block` to keep things on the same line as below:

Keep in mind things get wonky with Bootstrap as you shift to smaller screen-sizes but at least the display is consistent

View the snippet below in full screen as necessary to see the effect.

```css
#CustomForm .width-override {
  width: 50% !important;
}

#CustomForm .form-control,
#CustomForm .width-override+p.form-control-static {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="form-horizontal">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="inputEmail3" class="col-xs-2 control-label">Email</label>
        <div class="col-xs-6">
          <input type="email" class="form-control" id="inputEmail3" placeholder="Email">
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-1">
          <p class="form-control-static">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-question-sign "></span>
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="inputPassword3" class="col-xs-2 control-label">Password</label>
        <div class="col-xs-6">
          <input type="password" class="form-control" id="inputPassword3" placeholder="Password">
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-1">
          <p class="form-control-static">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-question-sign "></span>
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
    <div id="CustomForm" class="form-horizontal">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="inputEmail3" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Email</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
          <input type="email" class="form-control width-override" id="inputEmail3" placeholder="Email">
          <p class="form-control-static">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-question-sign "></span>
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="inputPassword3" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Password</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
          <input type="password" class="form-control width-override" id="inputPassword3" placeholder="Password">
          <p class="form-control-static">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-question-sign "></span>
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```